# Multi-level card marking table for write barriers

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

How does Hotspot and other generational garbage collectors avoid spending huge amount of time scanning card tables? See http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html which says that the size of a card is 512 bytes and a card itself is 1 byte.

So for a 512 mb large heap, you have a 1 mb large card table to scan for each gc cyle. This seems prohibitive. And heaps are often much larger than 512 mb.

To solve this problem, Slava Pestov when working on Factor introduced decks: http://factor-language.blogspot.se/2008/05/garbage-collection-throughput.html It groups cards into decks and you only scan cards in decks that are dirty. This optimization avoids scanning the whole card table but the drawback is that the write barrier requires two writes, one to the card table and one to the deck table. This technique seems to be Slava Pestov's own invention and I haven't seen it used anywhere else.

My question is what methods does Hotspot, .NET, Mono and all other generational garbage collectors employing card tables use to avoid the problem with having to scan huge card tables?

Interestingly I found a thread written by Alexey Razogin (the person who wrote the first blog article) about implementing super-cards in Hotspot: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-dev/2011-July/002889.html So it appears that the performance problem may be known and the solution may be these deck structures.

Comment: I think this question is too broad for SO. It also requires discussion, and expects multiple (correct) answers. My personal POV is that while the cost of write barrier would be incurred on all mutator threads and seems unavoidable, card table scanning can be parallelised, can be scanned efficiently with vector instructions, can be pre-summarized by collectors, the coarseness of cards can be tuned, etc. Therefore, it seems simpler write barriers is a saner tradeoff. There is a good discussion and references on write barrier design in "The Garbage Collection Handbook": http://gchandbook.org/

Comment: Would it be better if I only mentioned Hotspot? The answer I'm looking for is what exactly, if anything, it does to solve the linear card table scan problem for large heaps.

Comment: I think yeah, explicitly stating a particular implementation you are interested in would help. But either way, you have already half-answered your question, read Ragozin's posts carefully: he basically proposed vectorization of card table scans (*not* super-cards or 2-level card marks), he also pointed at how Parallel GC splits the card scanning work, etc. I think nothing really beats reading up the relevant section of GC handbook  ;)